# Wordpress transfer from localhost (WAMP) to live (IIS) results in blank screens

Tags: wordpress, iis, wamp

I'm moving a Wordpress site from localhost to live - which seems to be on an IIS server, and am getting the white screen of death.

Followed the codex instructions to a tee and all the wp-config is correct, then realized the target host was IIS (not sure if that's the issue but it might be). Don't know how to fix it, though.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: This question should probably be posted on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) instead.

Comment: @LewisJackson well, I'm not certain it's the servers that's causing the problem. Just might be the reason.

Comment: It could be anything, check your error log and trace it from there. Easiest fix is to put in on a Apache/Linux server, see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hosting_WordPress

Comment: Migrating a site from Apache to IIS is certainly possible. Excuse me for asking the obvious but do you have MySQL and PHP installed on the new server? Keep in mind that the connection string to the database instance will have most certainly changed when changing servers, unless it is hosted elsewhere.

Comment: @LewisJackson - sometimes the obvious needs to be asked. PHP 5 is installed, but it seems ASP and ColdFusion are as well. Would that interfere in any way?

Comment: @itamar I wouldn't say so, but I don't have any experience with ColdFusion. My first step would probably be to host a test PHP file calling the [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) function, to ensure PHP is working as it should.

Comment: @LewisJackson okay so phpinfo.php in the root with `<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

// Show just the module information.
// phpinfo(8) yields identical results.
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?>`

Still gives me a blank page.

Comment: go to your `wp-config.php` and set `wp-debug` mode to true, then it will flash errors instead of blank screen. .. no one can guess what actually problem is .. though you have option to see

Comment: @itamar in that case I would assume PHP isn't working correctly. If I was you I would post this question on [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com) and hopefully you might get a better response. If you do, make sure you include the fact that `phpinfo` is giving a blank page also.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have PHP installed on IIS, a WSOD generally it's caused from a 500. Since .htaccess files here have no power do you have a correct web.config sitting on the root of your Wordpress folder?

If not create one and go step by step:

- The home file should be index.php otherwise IIS will inherit the default.asp
- Enable remote error reporting to show on screen what's really happening.
- Read the PHP error logs.

If you succeed the next step will be to do extra configuration for the [permalinks as described in the Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite)